# Auto-generated hidden header based on folder

Tags: postman

I am working on existing collection of Postman requests.  One surprising behavior I have noticed is that when I move a request in/out of a specific Postman collection folder, one request header ("Authorization") is added/removed from the request automatically.

In other words - an existing request is having 8 headers but when I move the request out of specific folder, 1 header is removed automatically and only 7 headers are left on the request.

I would like to change this behavior so that the header stays with the request irrespective of its location.  I mimicked my folder's Authorization tab and Pre-request Script tab with existing folder's tabs, but of no help.

Please suggest how to address it.

Comment: Is the Auth set at the Collection level and all the other elements set to inherit from parent? That would/could make that header behave like that. You could set the Auth at the folder level so that it's in there explicitly. There's a bunch on information context missing from this explanation of what your collection looks like.

Comment: I have set my folder's Auth tab to match with original folder's Auth tab.  Please suggest what more details are needed to address the issue.  Thanks for your help!